# How can I render text under a textbox?

Tags: html, css

Make something like in html/css

[image]

Comment: Are you willing to accept any kind of cross-browser limitations? Does it *have* to work in IE 6..?

Comment: doesn't have to work ie6

Comment: that's a relief, since [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843547/how-can-i-render-text-under-a-textbox/3843599#3843599) probably doesn't.

Comment: You've already got three good answers here. I guess you need to pick the one of which fits your code better. @DavidTomas's is probably the most accurate - with the addition of a form for later us. @Gus has a nice succinct answer. Mine is complete but without the form field. Ignore the 'hacking' and the none IE friendly questions - this should not have problems in any browser

Comment: Thanks @Glycerine =) I couldn't promise IE compatibility, since I don't have a version of Windows to test on (yay!), so I deliberately *didn't* assure it...that said, I think it should work. It was only the `display: inline-block` on `block`-level elements (`fieldset`s) that worried me. I've since used floats and `display: block;` to work around that restriction, so should be okay now. I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to @Gus' answer, but a little more semantic:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="day" id="day" />
    <label for="day">Day</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="hour" id="hour" />
    <label for="hour">Hour</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  <input type="text" name="min" id="min" />
    <label for="min">Min</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="sec" id="sec" />
    <label for="sec">Sec</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

With the following CSS:

```
fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset > input,
fieldset > label {
  display: block;
  width: 8em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Live demo posted at: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/erepu4/).

---

**Edited** to make it a just a little prettier...

New CSS:

```
form {
  width: 49.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
fieldset {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
  fieldset:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset > input,
fieldset > label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
fieldset > input {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

And revised demo (again) at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/erepu4/2/)

Answer (score 5):

You can do what you want by wrapping each input and label in div elements, and floating the divs.

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JXhqz/)

HTML:

```
<div class="boxwrap">
    <div>
        <input type="text" size="6" />
        <h5>label1</h5>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" size="6" />
        <h5>label2</h5>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" size="6" />
        <h5>label3</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfloat"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.boxwrap div {
    float: left ;
}
div.boxwrap div h5 {
    text-align: center ;
}
div.clearfloat {
    clear: both ;
}
```

Comment: I realise that paying attention to real (x)html elements seems to have fallen out of vogue, but seriously? There are several more-semantic elements easily available and purpose-built for this `<label for="idOfInput">` for example, it provides a nice onClick-focus event as well as a semantic relationship between elements (the `label` and the `input`)... There are more, but I sort of feel like I'm being petty.

Answer (score 2):

It's crude, but you could add an absolutely positioned div with that text in it and position it where it's needed. You'd probably also have to position the textboxes absolutely.

You might also be able to get away with a negative margin at the top (probably not in IE, though).

Answer (score 1):

No hacking involved - should be all browsers friendly.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.date-container {
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.input {
    width: 35px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
.field input {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.name {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
<div class="date-container">
    <div class="input">

        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name="day" id="day">
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            day
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input">

        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name="hour" id="hour">
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            Min
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name="min" id="min">
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            day
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name="sec" id="sec">
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            Sec
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most semantic approach (and it works all the way back to IE6, no worries):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            fieldset {
                border: none;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            label {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 75%;
                margin-right: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 30px;
            }

            input {
                width: 30px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="day" id="day">
                    Day
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="hour" id="hour">
                    Hour
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="minute" id="minute">
                    Min
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="second" id="second">
                    Sec
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```